# Determining an equation for a sphere

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, surfaces

my question is:

Given a line **S**: $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x+y-1=0 \\ 
y+3z-2=0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$ 
I need to determine the equation of a sphere having the center on line **S** and tangent to the plane $z=0.$
The cartesian equation of the line **S** $= ( -1,2,0 ) + ( 3,-3,1 )t.$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that the solution is not unique ?

Comment: I wouldn’t call that a “Cartesian equation” for the line. It would more commonly be called “parametric.” The system of two equations that you started with are Cartesian.

Answer (score 2):

Take any point on the line and consider the sphere centered on this point, with a radius equal to $|z|$. It fulfills the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

A point of $S$ has cordinates
$$y=2-3t$$
$$x=1-y=3t-1$$
$$z=t$$

its distance to plane $z=0$ is the radius

$$r=\frac{|t|}{1}$$

the equation of the sphere is

$$(x+1-3t)^2+(y+3t-2)^2+(z-t)^2=t^2$$